# Is there any support in computers nowadays for cd-rom drive specified in details?

Tags: windows, audio, microsoft-virtual-pc, ms-dos

It had 3.5 mm socket for headphones on the front panel and volume control and worked as ATAPI IDE. I saw this device working only with MS-DOS and WIN98. Will be the virtual pc capable to emulate it? (My software - the Academic American encyclopedia - needs it.) Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to find a computer with an IDE cable. Of you'll need to check with the software publishers for clarification on that "requirement".

Comment: You can access that online these days, or download it as an ePub or pdf - I found this ref https://archive.org/details/academicamerican21grol Seems you need to register, but there's no cost mentioned [that I can see]

Comment: You don't even mention what software you're using for the virtual PC!  If it's DOSBox, I believe it can emulate such a drive, but I'm not sure you're correct that it -must- be an IDE/ATA drive.  More likely a SATA-connected DVD drive might work just as well.

Comment: @Debra Please, don't you know how to emulate the following two lines in DOSBox. The first must be in CONFIG.SYS and the second in AUTOEXEC.BAT. Otherwise an application error occurs: `DEVICE=C:\PCD650S\MTMCDAI.SYS /D:MSCD001`, `C:\PCD650S\MSCDEX /D:MSCD001 /M:10 /L:E` Thank you.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you! I knew the publisher own support, but it has probably finished. This is useful replacement.